# Real-time page feed subscription failing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I'm trying to set up a subscription on my app to one of my pages' feeds using the Facebook [real-time api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). It looks pretty straight forward but for some reason I can't actually get myself subscribed. I am trying to subscribe using this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<target_page_id>/subscriptions?access_token=<app_token>
&object=page&fields=feed&callback_url=<my_callback>&verify_token=123
```

And am verifying success/failure here:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<target_page_id>/subscriptions?access_token=<app_token>
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: the answer is

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7367948/how-to-subscribe-to-real-time-updates-for-a-facebook-pages-wall/7384450#7384450

Comment: This may give idea of a complete flow of page subscription: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-updates-for-facebook-page.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1stly, url to subscribe is
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/subscriptions?access_token=app_token
&object=page&fields=feed&callback_url=my_callback&verify_token=123

you should use app_id instead of page_id

also, sadly there is documentation or api bug 
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/134146190023217

Comment: This may give idea of a complete flow of page subscription: http://tech-brains.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-updates-for-facebook-page.html